# Joomla website: How to remove index.php from url?

Tags: url-rewriting

I've been fighting with this problem quite some time and really need some help.

So I want to remove the index.php from my Joomla website url. I have Joomla version 3.4.1

This is what I've done so far:

- in administrator's global configuration I've set Use URL rewriting - Yes
- htaccess.txt is now renamed as .htaccess

But when I try to go to some page I get this message:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me!

Comment: Clear your cache and check!!

Comment: what do you mean by cache?

Comment: There is caching in joomla to make sites faster. It can be cleared under global config. Read this to know more about cache https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/cache/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things you need to do.

- Assuming you are using Apache, make sure you have indeed renamed the htaccess.txt file to .htaccess

The .txt extension is hidden by default in Windows.

To be certain that you have named the file correctly, open the htaccess.txt file in notepad, go to Save As and give it the name ".htaccess" and save it (With the quotes!)

- IIS 7 users must rename the web.config.txt file to web.config

At this stage, if you continue getting a 404 Not Found Error:

- Clear the system cache from the admin panel by going to : System > Clear Cache.

Mark everything there and press the Delete button.

Things should be working now.

After doing all this if you start getting a 500 Internal Server Error ( which happened in my case ), make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled.

To do this:

- Find the httpd.conf file. If you are using WAMP, simply click on its icon > Apache > httpd.conf
- Find the line "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" and make sure it isn't commented. If it is, remove the # sign in front of it.
- If you made any changes to the httpd.conf file, make sure to restart the Apache service. You can do this simply by left clicking the WAMP icon > Restart All Services.

This should do the trick.